# Views not getting overlapped in a FrameLayout when ToggleButton is a child

Tags: android, android-framelayout, android-togglebutton

I have an upvote button on top of which I have to display the number of upvotes.
I have used a ToggleButton for upvote and a textview to display the number of upvotes. I used a FrameLayout to overlap textview which shows number of followers on top of upvote button. But the textview is not getting overlapped. Instead it is hidden behind the upvote button.

Here is my FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/position"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/thumbs_up"
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn=""
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:button="@drawable/check"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/numberOfUpvotes"
        android:text="120"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: try android:elevation attribute on your textview.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar thanks! It solved the problem!

Comment: But what might be the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Because the toggle button has a default elevation, that's why it's rendering above the textview.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `android:elevation` attribute on your `TextView` because the `ToggleButton` has a default elevation that is why it's rendering above the `TextView`.